# We have a aspx page on our iis7 server, which fails to work on production but works fine on development

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Basically we have this aspx script generated by another company, which we need to run, we normally just use coldfusion, for our company.

However this app is an aspx.

We have both a development and production server, it works flawlessly on our dev server, but it fails to work at all in the production server.

It uses a javascript function called _doPostBack.

I have compared the aspx files on dev/prod line by line, and they are 100% identical.

So I need some ideas what iis7 setting to change to allow this to work. Since we didn't do anything special to make it work on our development server.

Our Prodution server is sql2008, iis7, win 2008 i believe.

Our Development server is sql 2005 express, iis7, vista business edition.

Any suggestions or tips we can do?

And in firebug it generates no javascript errors of any code, but the navigation links do nothing.

The page itself displays, on the left is a list of links, which if clicked on, should change the content on the right/main content area.

This works fine on dev, it doesn't work at all on production. It does display the page, show's no javascript errors, but the navigation links do not work.

There is no external javascript file, so it must be something in iis.

Thanks

Comment: Very hard to diagnose without code sample.  Can you post a little bit of the file, or at least the button code.  Also, since it's an aspx page (.NET) make sure that you have the same version of the .NET framework installed on both servers.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider reinstalling asp.net on the box that isn't working. Can be done from command line using `aspnet_regiis -i`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Other than that I have no idea. Sounds like a config issue to me though..

Answer (score 1):

In the IIS settings, make sure the ASP.NET System Services is running and verify that ASP.NET exists in the Role Services. Also check the Application Pools and in the Advanced Settings, you can check the .Net framework version.

What happens if you try to acccess a page you create called test.aspx with plain text?

Comment: Good call on the plaintext file test.

Comment: I just ran a simple hello world aspx file to production to see if it was an aspx issue or not. I used the bottom scripts from http://www.asp101.com/lessons/firstpage.asp. Then I got the following error. Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL:

Comment: Oops nevermind, I had the url in the wrong spot, that hello world. aspx file works...no errors. What else can i try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the page locally on the production server, sometimes things will work locally but not remotely if it's an IIS issue.

Have you verified that the appropriate .Net framework is installed on the machine and that the page resides in an application in IIS?

Comment: Intersting idea, and not sure. The page does reside in an application.

Answer (score 0):

Using IE8, press F12 to bring up the developer tools. Inside the tools you can examine the various scripts that are (or will be) running, and start debugging. Start the debugger and set a breakpoint where the _doPostBack function is being called (or inside the function itself) and see what is actually happening.

Also, you may want to fire up [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and compare the HTTP requests between your development and production servers. It is entirely possible that something else isn't returning as expected (like a call to WebResource.axd) in production that works fine in dev.